# .isDisplayed - Selenium + Appium

Tags: android, selenium, testing, automation, appium

I'm just a beginner in automation testing. Know only c, c++ and PHP. Now I want to learn java by working with automation tests.

I want to check if the element exists and if it's visible, I found an explanation on this page and for check if it's visible I have to use .isDisplayed() method but I can't understand why my IDE can't find this method? when I call it, it's "red" so not found.

There is a link to img from my ide: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxLEN.jpg

You can see that method .isEmpty() is normally working... but have no idea why .isDisplayes is red ;/

Couldn't upload this image cos my chrome doing some crazy shit when I'm uploading it.

Sorry for stupid question -> I'm learning

Comment: Please, don't post code your code as a linked image, but add it as text in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misspelled isDisplayed(). You have isDispalyed() :)

Comment: Hey, you're right but it's still red :( and have no idea why ;/

It seems that i'm missing some library...